# how to check for an empty array java

Tags: java, arrays

I wanted to know if this code is valid for checking whether an array is empty, or should I check for null?

```
if(arrayName={})
  System.out.println("array empty");
else System.out.println("array not empty");
```

Thank you!

Comment: That depends on what you mean by __empty__ .

Comment: *"I wanted to know if this code is valid for checking whether an array is empty"* — the code you posted doesn't even compile. In the future, it's probably faster to just **try compiling your code** rather than asking people on the internet to look at it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In array class we have a static variable defined "length", which holds the number of elements in array object. You can use that to find the length as:

```
if(arrayName.length == 0)
  System.out.println("array empty");
else 
  System.out.println("array not empty");
```

Answer (score 12):

I would consider using ArrayUtils.is empty by adding Apache Commons Lang from here http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi

The big advantage is this will null check the array for you in a clean and easily readible way.

You can then do:

```
if (ArrayUtils.isEmpty(arrayName) {
    System.out.printLn("Array empty");
} else {
    System.out.printLn("Array not empty");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As poited out in the other answers, the `length` property of `Array` will give the length of the array. But it is always recommended to check if the array is `null` before doing any operation on it or else it will throw `NullPointerException` if the array is `null`.

```
     if (array != null) {
            if (array.length == 0)
                System.out.println("Empty Array Size=0");
            else
                System.out.println("Array Not Empty -  Size = " + array.length);

        } else
            System.out.println("array is null");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, because array literals don't work that way.  Replace `arrayName={}` with `arrayName.length==0`, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

To check empty try like this:

```
if (arr.length == 0) {
 System.out.println("array is empty");
}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

proudandhonour's answer is on the right track but won't work for all possible values of `arrayName`, specifically that case in which `arrayName` hasn't been defined and is `null`.  In that case, the code:

```
if(arrayName.length == 0)
  System.out.println("array empty");
else 
  System.out.println("array not empty");
```

will fail with a `NullPointerException.`  TimeTravel's answer correctly tests for this case and correctly handles all possible values for `arrayName`.  The only downside is that his code is more verbose than it needs to be.

Java provides *short circuit evaluation* of Boolean expressions.  Specifically the result of `(false && xx)` is `false` for all possible values of `xx`.  Therefore when evaluating the first operand of a Boolean `&&` operator, the JVM will ignore the 2nd operand if the 1st evaluates to false.

Exploiting this, we can write:

```
if (arrayName != null && arrayName.length > 0)
    { System.out.println("The array length > 0"); }
else
    { System.out.println("The array is null or empty"); }
```

There is also the *ternary operator* which provides a mechanism for inlining if-then-else expressions.  This can improve readability in some circumstances:

```
System.out.println((arrayName == null)
    ? "The arrayName variable is null"
    : (arrayName.length < 1)
        ? "The array length is zero"
        : "The array length is " + String.valueOf(arrayName.length)
);
```